# Is there any recourse if an exchange/wallet service fails?

Tags: coinbase.com

I recently used Coinbase to acquire some Bitcoins, my second Bitcoin purchase using their exchange.  The first transaction worked as expected however the second purchase seems to have encountered an internal error inside Coinbase.  After waiting the week for the USD transfer from my bank to change from "PENDING" to "COMPLETE" in the system I tried to transfer a portion of the purchased BTC to a bitcoin address.  The transaction appeared to be processing but the BTC never arrived at the destination address.  The following day there was no indication that the transaction had ever happened and the previously "COMPLETED" BTC purchase was once again "PENDING" with an estimate of 1 hour.  It has now been "PENDING" at the hour estimate for 6 days.

I have attempted to resolve this with Coinbase and I've only received an email saying we'll "fix it as soon as possible".  They have held the funds deducted from my account for some time now.  Is there anything I could do at this late date from the banking side of things?

EDIT:  Coinbase finally resolved whatever their issue was and the BTC was successfully delivered to my address.  Just over 14 days on this transaction where the first one took the advertised 7 day wait.

Comment: Your question and its explanation are not really related. If you modify the explanation, you might get an answer to the question. Otherwise, your explanation sounds more like material for [/r/bitcoin](http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin) or Coinbase's preferred ticketing or forum solution.